# getBoundingClientRect returning same value in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs

I'm having trouble getting getBoundingClientRect() working in Google Chrome. My code is the following:

React.js render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="TapTwo-container" ref="clickContainer" onClick={this._handleTap}>
            <div id="TapTwo-forkContainer" className="TapTwo-forkContainer u-animationLinear u-animationLoop tapTwo-moveForkLeft" ref="fork">
                <img src="img/fork.png" className="tapTwo-fork"/>
            </div>
            <div className="TapTwo-pieContainer">
                <img src="img/pie.png" className="tapTwo-pie" />
                <img src="img/plate.png" className="tapTwo-plate"/>
            </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

The function _handleTap does the following:

```
_handleTap() {
    let element = document.getElementById('TapTwo-forkContainer');
    let box = element.getBoundingClientRect()

    let top  = box.top;
    let left = box.left;

    console.log(Math.round(top),Math.round(left));
}
```

Things to note here: The TapTwo-forkContainer gets animated + transformed with CSS. It moves from the left of the screen to the right, for example, one of the keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes moveForkLeft {
    0% {
         transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(1250px, 0);
    }
}
```

When I test it in Firefox, the every click I get a different value based on the position of the TapTwo-forkContainer. However, when I check it in Google Chrome (41.0.2272.118), I get the same values over and over again.

Here's a demo (try spamming the Click me button and see the values returned in the console)

http://jsfiddle.net/d26cpdfk/4/

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/d26cpdfk/. On click I get different values reported by getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: I also worked with your link, and updated it a bit, showing the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/d26cpdfk/4/, try spam clicking the click me button.

Comment: getBoundingClientRect seems buggy indeed. Try using getComputedStyle. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like getBoundingClientRect is buggy in Chrome. You can use getComputedStyle to get the x or y value in an animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/d26cpdfk/1/

```
var element = document.getElementById('element')

    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(element.getBoundingClientRect().left)

        var cs = window.getComputedStyle(element).transform
        var x = parseFloat(cs.split(', ')[4])
        console.log('getBoundingClientRect:',element.getBoundingClientRect().left, 'getComputedStyle:',x)
    }, false)
```

Comment: Awesome. The JSFiddle now looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d26cpdfk/5/ and that seems to work fine!